How do I add a variable to a method using tkinter?
I am studying python and have the following task:
I want my code to display the text the user wrote when using the Button method from tkinter.
However it shows nothing, I believe the variable (text) is not working inside the method (button_clicked).
It also seems I'm shadowing my variable (text), and I already tried to make it global, to no effect.
Any help would be much appreciated.
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.title("My first GUI program")

text="My text"

my_label = Label(text = "Hello", font= ("Arial", 24, "bold"))
my_label.pack()

#Studying Entry
input = Entry(width=10)
input.pack()
text = input.get()

#Button
def button_clicked():
   -my_label["text"] = text

button = Button(text="Click Me", command = button_clicked)
button.pack()

window.mainloop()


How did you "tried to make it global"?

is -my_label["text"] = text a typo? Because -my_label is not a valid variable name.

You need to call text = input.get() inside button_clicked().

You evaluate text = input.get() before the UI is shown. Get the text in the callback. my_label["text"] = input.get()

Don't use input. It is valid for Python


I want my code to display the text the user wrote when using the
Button method from tkinter.


You are utilizing Python for valid input. Avoid using this.
Avoid utilizing the wildcard from the tkinter import *library. Use
import tkinter as tk and then use the tk. prefix.
You have typo error. change this on line 10, -my_label to my_label
Add .configure inside button_clicked() function.

Snippet:
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("My first GUI program")

text="My text"

#Button
def button_clicked():
   txt=my_entry.get() 
   my_label.configure(text=txt)

my_label = tk.Label(text = "Hello", font= ("Arial", 24, "bold"))
my_label.pack()

#Studying Entry
my_entry = tk.Entry(width=10)
my_entry.pack()
 

 

button = tk.Button(text="Click Me", command = button_clicked)
button.pack()

window.mainloop()


The text isn't displayed, because you're not retrieving the text from your Entry widget when the button is clicked. In your code you're trying to retrieve the Entry's text after you created it and that's why nothing it's displayed. You can update your button_clicked() function like this:
def button_clicked():
   my_label["text"] = input.get()

If you want to store the text inside the text variable and display it, you can use this code:
def button_clicked():
   global text
   text = input.get()

   my_label["text"] = text


Avoid using global.
